# How to use sed to replace url with special characters stored into a variale

Tags: linux, sed

I have two URLs with special characters stored into variables:

```
echo $old
http://someip:port/url/lang/125487524ghgfdf4/3849.ts

echo $new
http://someip/url/id/playlist.m3u8?ttl=1518493297&allow&l=0&allow2=7d3196ed5fcf737aefa7dceb9d626df8
```

I use sed to replace `$old` with `$new`:

```
sed -i -e "s|$old|$new|g" file.conf
```

But instead of replacing the URL, sed seems to insert `$old` into every instance of `&` in `$new` resulting in this:

```
http://someip/url/id/playlist.m3u8?ttl=1518493297http://someip:port/url/lang/125487524ghgfdf4/3849.tsallowhttp://someip:port/url/lang/125487524ghgfdf4/3849.tsl=0http://someip:port/url/lang/125487524ghgfdf4/3849.tsallow2=7d3196ed5fcf737aefa7dceb9d626df8
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` in the sed replacement string is replaced by the whole match (see, for example, the fourth paragraph of the [GNU sed documentation for `s///`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)). You have to escape it if you don't want that:

```
sed -i -e "s|$old|${new//&/\\&}|g" file.conf
```

`${new//&/\\&}` is a parameter expansion that replaces every instance of `&` with `\&` in `$new`.